# C++ if statement with ||

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have to print an error if the gender entered is not M/m/F/f/X/x but my if statement always returns true

```
cout << "Please enter the candidate's information "
        "(enter 'X' to exit).";
cout << endl << "gender: ";
cin.get(gender);
cin.ignore(1000,'\n');

if (gender != 'M' || gender != 'm' || gender != 'F' ||
    gender != 'f' || gender != 'X' || gender != 'x')
    {
        cout << "error";
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49592665/edit).

Comment: @Ron Presumably it's "Why does my if statement always return true and how can I fix it?". This isn't phrased as a question, but it's still clear what's being asked.

Comment: Can you find any letter in the alphabet for which the following statement is false: `the letter is not "M" or the letter is not "F"`. Once you figure out why this statement can never be false, you'll figure out the answer to your question all by yourself.

Comment: Why do you think that your condition should ever be false?

Comment: If the gender is `'F'`, you should have seen that the very first condition `gender != 'M'` is `true`.  Thus the entire `if()` is true, since it is grouped using `||`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: You should use `cerr` instead of `cout` for your errors.

Comment: If you are operating on an singlebyte character set you can save yourself some work and use `tolower` to convert gender to lower case. Half as many comparisons that way.

Comment: It should be `gender != 'M' && gender != 'm' && gender != 'F' ...`

Answer (score 5):

You are using the wrong boolean operator.

`gender` can't be all of them at the same time. Hence, the conditional will always evaluate to `true`. You need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
if (gender != 'M' && gender != 'm' && gender != 'F' ||
    gender != 'f' && gender != 'X' && gender != 'x')
{
   cout << "error";
}
```

It find it more readable to use:

```
// Define a function that encapsulates the logic 
bool isValidGender(char gender)
{
   return (gender == 'M' || gender == 'm' || gender == 'F' ||
           gender == 'f' || gender == 'X' || gender == 'x');
}
```

Use the function.

```
if (!isValidGender(gender))
{
   cout << "error";
}
```

---

You can implement `isValidGender` using a `switch` statement too.

```
bool isValidGender(char gender)
{
   switch (gender)
   {
      case 'M':
      case 'm':
      case 'F':
      case 'f':
      case 'X':
      case 'x':
         true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

You can convert `gender` to a lowercase letter first to simplify the `switch` statement.

```
   switch (std::tolower(gender))
   {
      case 'm':
      case 'f':
      case 'x':
         true;
   }
```

Comment: I would use a `switch` instead of a bunch of `!=` comparisons

Comment: @RemyLebeau, interesting thought. I don't recall having used that before.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||` because you want to trigger an error when `gender` does not equal **any** of them.

```
if (gender != 'M' && gender != 'm' && gender != 'F' &&
    gender != 'f' && gender != 'X' && gender != 'x')
{
   cout << "error";
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `!` and `||` logic with `==` instead of `!=`.

i.e. when `gender` *does not equal* any of them trigger the error like this:

```
if (!(gender == 'M' || gender == 'm' || gender == 'F' ||
    gender == 'f' || gender == 'X' || gender == 'x'))
{
   cout << "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change **||** to **&&** like

```
if (gender != 'M' && gender != 'm' && gender != 'F' &&
gender != 'f' && gender != 'X' && gender != 'x')
{
    cout << "error";
}
```